# In bash, is it possible to use an integer variable in a brace expansion

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, for

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

upperlim=10

for i in {0..10}
do
echo $i
done

for i in {0..$upperlim}
do
echo $i
done
```

The first `for` loop (*without* the variable `upperlim` in the loop control) works fine, but the second `for` loop (*with* the variable `upperlim` in the loop control) does not.  Is there any way that I can modify the second `for` loop so that it works?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: hm, even `for i in {0..$((upperlim))}; do echo $i; done`does not work

Comment: possible cross site duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169511/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-range-of-numbers-defined-by-variables-in-bash

Comment: An external link that answers this: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-iterate-over-a-variable-range-of-numbers-in-bash/

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The reason for this is the order in which things occur in bash. Brace expansion occurs **before** variables are expanded. In order to accomplish your goal, you need to use C-style for loop:

```
upperlim=10

for ((i=0; i<=upperlim; i++)); do
   echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: And works for `zsh` as well (but not for `csh`, `tcsh`).

Comment: TIL double parantheses in bash: https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html

Answer (score 39):

To complete this in your style using nothing but built-ins you'd have to use eval:

```
d=12

for i in `eval echo {0..$d}`
do
echo $i
done
```

But with `seq`:

```
lowerlimit=0
upperlimit=12

for i in $(seq $lowerlimit $upperlimit)
do
echo $i
done
```

Personally I find the use of `seq` to be more readable.

Answer (score 12):

**The POSIX way**

If you care about portability, use the [example from the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04_01):

```
i=2
END=5
while [ "$i" -le "$END" ]; do
    echo "$i"
    i=$(($i+1))
done
```

Output:

```
2
3
4
5
```

Things which are *not* POSIX:

- `(( ))` without dollar, although it is a common extension [as mentioned by POSIX itself](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04).
- `[[`. `[` is enough here. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542832/bash-if-difference-between-square-brackets-and-double-square-brackets
- `for ((;;))`
- `seq`
- `{start..end}`, and that cannot work with variables as mentioned [by the Bash manual](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5723526/895245).
- `let i=i+1`: [POSIX 7 2. Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04) does not contain the word `let`, and it fails on `bash --posix` 4.3.42
- the dollar at `i=$i+1` might be required, but I'm not sure. [POSIX 7 2.6.4 Arithmetic Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04) says:

  > If the shell variable *x* contains a value that forms a valid integer constant, optionally including a leading plus or minus sign, then the arithmetic expansions `"$((x))"` and `"$(($x))"` shall return the same value.

  but reading it literally that does not imply that `$((x+1))` expands since `x+1` is not a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach will not work since in bash brace-expansion occurs before parameter expansion. You need to expand the variable before.

You can work around with [eval](http://ss64.com/bash/eval.html):

```
upperlim=10
eval '
        for i in {0..'"$upperlim"'}
        do
                echo $i
        done
'
```

With [While loop](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_02.html):

```
upperlim=10
#with while
start=0
while [[ $start -le $upperlim ]]
do
    echo "$start"
    ((start = start + 1))
done
```

Also you can do it with [seq command](http://ss64.com/bash/seq.html):

```
upperlim=10
#seq
for i in $(seq "$upperlim"); do
  echo "$i"
done
```

If you want to run with `for i in {0..$upperlim}` you will need to use kornshell. eg:

```
#!/bin/ksh
upperlim=10

for i in {0..$upperlim}
do
        echo $i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in $(seq ${1:-1} ${2:-10}); do                                            
        echo $i                                                                 
done 

                                                                       
                                                                            
i=${1:-1}                                                                       
while (( $i <= ${2:-10} )); do                                                  
        echo $i                                                                 
        i=$(($i + 1))                                                           
done
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note however that your answer would benefit from some more explanation on what it is you are doing and how and why this contributes to answering the original question.