# bash + how to set variable instead array element

Tags: bash, shell-script, array

we can build array list of a..z range as the following

example1

```
list=({a..z})
echo $list
echo ${list[*]}
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

but in case we want to set variable in the array as the follwing

```
var=a
list=({$var..z})
echo ${list[*]}
{a..z}
```

we not get the values from a..z as example1

How to set it so we can print all characters of the alphabet?

Comment: You cannot achieve that in `bash`, because range/brace expansion happens before parameter expansion. So it won't know to expand `$var`

Comment: @Inian may as well post that as an answer.

Comment: @terdon: I know ton's of duplicates of this on SO, I thought it should be there here too. If so we could close it

Comment: or this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/55392/170373 well, it's about numbers only